# Windows 8 failing to install on VirtualBox in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, windows-8

[image: First Error while starting the Virtual Machine]

[image: Second Error, After displaying windows 8 logo for 3 minutes]

I'm getting the errors attached as screenshots above when I try to start the virtual machine so that it installs windows 8. When the first error popped out, I clicked on continue and it brought the windows 8 logo for 3 minutes then it showed the black screen with the second error. I have also tried it with Physical Address Extension disabled and it brings the Windows 8 Recovery error. The host machine is a 4GB ram Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T6570 @ 2.10GHz × 2 and the Virtual machine has 1GB with 1 CPU. How do i get this virtual win8 machine to work?

Comment: The OS referenced is Mac instead of Win 8.  Hardware virtualization enable is the real question though.

Comment: I updated virtualBox and the problem went away without any change in my virtual machine settings.

Answer (score -1):

you need to enable in the BIOS hardware acceleration config (VT-X or AMD-V, based on your cpu).